# Required a bean of type 'com.ganesh.utils.JwtUtils2' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

There are many questions for this error, most of them related to repository and service classes but I couldn't find a one relative to exactly my case.

My package structure inside `src/main/java/com/ganesh/`looks like this

```
├── ApiApplication.java
├── interceptors
│   └── AuthorizationInterceptor.java
└── utils
    └── JwtUtils.java
...
```

`JwtUtils` is defined as below

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
     ... 
}
```

And `AuthorizationInterceptor` defined as

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    ... 
}
```

The main class is defined as

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I run I get this error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jwtUtils in com.ganesh.interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor required a bean of type 'com.ganesh.utils.JwtUtils' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ganesh.utils.JwtUtils' in your configuration.
```

I'm not sure what I have missed.